# Restructure a list with brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

I work with the following list

```
data = {{a}, {{a, b}, {a, b}}, {{{a, b, c}}}};
```

In real, the dataset is much longer and each row has a different structure of having {}

I want to restructure it to:

```
{{a}, {a, b},  {a, b}, {a, b, c}}
```

Is this possible using `Flatten`. If not, what is the easiest way to do this.

A special case is when the data contains DateObjects like:

```
{{{DateObject[01 - 06 - 2020], "buy", 572.18, 
   DateObject[01 - 06 - 2020], "sell", 570.52}}, { 
  DateObject[01 - 12 - 2020], "buy", 
  616.2}, {DateObject[01 - 01 - 2021], "sell", 
  697.94`}, {DateObject[01 - 02 - 2021], "buy", 
  708.43`}, {DateObject[01 - 03 - 2021], "keep", 709.36`}}
```

Comment: `Level[data, {-2}]` ?

Comment: `Cases[data, {Except[_List]..}, Infinity]` or `Cases[data, _List?VectorQ, Infinity]` might be what you want. The suggestion by @BenIzd will only work if the elements of you lists are all atomic.

Comment: You could add your new test case to the question

Comment: Use `Replace[ReplaceRepeated[data, {{a__}} :> {a}], {a__List} :> a, {1}]` for your new test case.

Comment: also `List[data //. {a__List} :> a]` and `Replace[data, {a__List} :> a, All]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{a}, {{a, b}, {a, b}}, {{{a, b, c}}}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[data, {_?AtomQ , ___}, -1]
```

{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Join[Sequence @@ Map[Level[#, {Depth[#] - 2}] &, data]]

(*  {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}   *)
```

I am not sure if it will work in more complex cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{a}, {{a, b}, {a, b}}, {{{a, b, c}}}};

Cases[data, _?VectorQ, All]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{a}, {{a, b}, {a, b}}, {{{a, b, c}}}};
```

---

Using `Delete` and `Nest`:

```
f = Nest[Delete[#, {0}] &, #, Depth[#] - 2] &;

f /@ data

(*{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}*)
```